# Qt Signal "entered" is not connected to the slot

Tags: qt, signals, qtableview

Why QTableView connect signal **viewportEntered** works, but **entered** doesn't ?

```
QMetaObject::Connection connection;
connection = connect(ui->tableview, SIGNAL (viewportEntered()), this, SLOT (on_tv_viewportEntered())); // connection success - connection.d_ptr != 0
connection = connect(ui->tableview, SIGNAL (entered()), this, SLOT (on_tv_entered())); // connection error - connection.d_ptr == 0
```

If connect in the designer, everything works, but I need to connect from the code

Comment: It's entered (QModelIndex). I would suggest to use the new connect syntax checked at compile time.

Comment: provide a [mre], use new syntas: `connect(ui->tableview, &QAbstractItemView::entered, this, &YourClass::on_tv_entered)`

Comment: Yes, new connect syntax. Thanks to all !